# delete textbox default text only after one click, c# form

Tags: c#, forms, text, textbox, box

I would like to have my text deleted only once in my `Textbox` so that it wouldn't clear `Textbox` every time I click. My current code looks like:

```
private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = string.Empty;          
}
```

But how can I get it to only delete the text once?

Comment: what about - textBox1.Enabled = false; after that?
or some global boolean and if statement if you dont want to disable button

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. could you ask your qustions a bit more clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a simple boolean flag:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool firstClick = true;
```

And in your event handler:

```
private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (firstClick)
    {
        textBox1.Text = string.Empty;          
        firstClick = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but where to fit this boolean flag? :/ Those are my first hours of WFA programming, sorry.

Comment: @GasperRataj see my edit. Put it inside the declaration for your form's class.